# EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:5858 during jest test debugging

Tags: node.js, debugging, jestjs

Hot to avoid following error to be throw during debugging of [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) tests:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:5858
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1262:14)
    at listen (net.js:1298:10)
    at doListening (net.js:1397:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

I run my tests using

```
node --harmony --debug-brk=5858 node_modules/.bin/jest
```

The problem is that Jest is forking new process to run tests and the new process is trying to bind to the same debug port (5858 in this case) as parent process and the port is already occupied by the parent process.

Weird thing is that this error happens often but not always. Sometime the command above actually allowed to debug the tests.

Comment: try it with the command below but still get the same error "listen EADDRINUSE :::5858" node --debug node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --runInBain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `--runInBand` `jest` option. From documentation:

> --runInBand, -i
>   Run all tests serially in the current process
>   (rather than creating a worker pool of child
>   processes that run tests). This is sometimes
>   useful for debugging, but such use cases are
>   pretty rare.                         [boolean]

It simply prevents Jest from forking.

```
node --harmony --debug-brk=5858 node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand
```

Comment: czerny meant to say `--runInBand` not `--runInBain`