# Why everytime that I run jest this error EADDRINUSE pops up?

Tags: jestjs, supertest

Using `supertest` and `jest` Im learning to make test in restfull application

```
const app = require("../app");
const request = require("supertest")(app);


describe("Test API", () => {

    it("Buscar CPF que possui uma conexão apenas", async () => {
        const res = await request.get('/pessoas/buscar/13123213213123')

        const body = res.body;
        if (body.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
            expect(res.body.message).toBe("Person not found")
            expect(res.status).toBe(404)
        } else {
            expect(res.body).toEqual([{
                blabla:  "aahahah"
            }])
            expect(res.status).toBe(200)
        }
    });

});
```

I ran the jest with --watch:

> ```
> listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3030
> ```

Also, I do not know, if this test is correct, when I receive a Object inside array `[ { } ]`, I should use `toEqual`?

Trying this [eaddrinuse-127-0-0-15858-during-jest-test-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733634/eaddrinuse-127-0-0-15858-during-jest-test-debugging) does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:5858 during jest test debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733634/eaddrinuse-127-0-0-15858-during-jest-test-debugging)

Comment: Hey, it did  not work, I do not know why close the question. Should you wait a answer?